# AmazonSES: CNAME, критическая проблема

Tags: dns, amazon, яндекс-почта, cname, dkim

Не обновляются **DNS**-записи от **AmazonSES** DKIM.

Домен делегирован на pdd.yandex.ru.
Он работает.
Я пробовал добавлять произвольную TXT запись - добавилась через пол часа, т.е. всё хорошо.

http://src.unotes.ru/s/zb94comizw.png - там всё.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В левой части надо стереть "`.highfeed.ru`". Напр. должно быть что-то вроде

```
ouzhuyblablabla._domainkey   CNAME   ouzhuyblablabla.dkim.amazonses.com.
```

Из скриншота видно, что исправить надо 4 (четыре) строки.

P.S. Вы о чем вообще думаете за полчаса до НГ?! : )  С Праздником Вас )

Comment: @sergiks,
> Вы о чем вообще думаете за полчаса до НГ?! : )
мне например вообще было плевать на Новый Год :) Единственное о чем я думал- это чтобы Канада порвала Россию, потому что немалую сумму в тото на нее зарядил :)  
Мой НГ начался с финальным свистком :)  
Так что норм :)

Comment: Спасибо, изменил - жду результатов. Какой тут НГ когда релиз проекта?

Comment: Результат отрицательный. Записи обновились за 15 мин. CNAME не появились.
TXT появились когда в хосте указал @ - другое ничего не воспринимает.

Фантастика если честно.